# Combine rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rows

I have the columns "male" and "female" in a `data.frame`. The rows of these columns are numbers.

To make it more tidy, I would like to add a new column "gender" for male/female and right next to it, I want to combine the both existing columns "male" and "female" (with the numbers in it).

How can I do that? I tried `bind_rows()` and `mutate()` but failed.

Comment: Try with `gather` or `melt`

Comment: ... otherwise you'll need to make this question more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including sample data (such as `dput(head(x))`), code you've tried so far, and your expected output.

Comment: Always try to add reproducible data to your questions" XX

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using `bind_rows` and `mutate`, it sounds like you use dplyr in the tidyverse, so I would use the tidyr package to do this

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(Text = c("Foo","Bar","babel"),Male =c(1,2,3), Female = c(4,5,6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

gather(df, Gender, GenderValue, Male, Female)
```